# Bash script not running after MixMonitor ends recording

Tags: bash, asterisk

I'm trying to execute a bash script after MixMonitor finishes recording a call.

I tried: `same  => n,MixMonitor(${custom_path}/${filename},,convert-to-mp3 ${custom_path} ${filename})`

Then I tried it with a delay to make sure the wav exists: `same  => n,MixMonitor(${custom_path}/${filename},,echo convert-to-mp3 ${custom_path} ${filename} | at now + 1 minute)`

And finally I decided to move the script call to the line after StopMixMonitor(): `same  => n,System(echo /usr/bin/convert-to-mp3 ${custom_path} ${filename} | at now + 1 minute)`

Manually executing the script with or without delay from the asterisk console (starting with !) works.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Lame was installed at /usr/local/bin/lame, which is not seen by Asterisk.